# Code not working when use preventDefault on submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form0').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

Why is my alert not working? Have also tried it before the line `e.preventDeafault().

HTML:

```
<form action="/Calculation/ShowDetailAnnuity" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#Loader" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#CalcDetail" id="form0" method="post">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: can you share your HTML code too..

Comment: Title of question `Stop submit form not working` and `yes the form is not submitted doing like this` is contradictory statements. __What is the exact problem__

Comment: Im sorry, will make the title better. The problem is that my alert is not working in this case..

Comment: @RiteshChandora HTML up now

Comment: did you try giving alert alone in the function? Please make sure that there is no jQuery conflict happening. Try with alert alone

Comment: I have tried that, the alert works with $(document).ready(function () { alert("hello"); });

Comment: Can it be something with the fact that i'm using Ajax.BeginForm MVC4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using jquery, use onsubmit, if there is a jquery conflict:

```
<form action="/Calculation/ShowDetailAnnuity" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#Loader" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#CalcDetail" id="form0" method="post" onsubmit="alert('hello'); return false;">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Or use `e.stopPropagation();` after `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form0').submit(function (e) {

        alert("hello");

        return false;
    });
});
```